# Geometry nodes attribute sample texture precision?

Tags: texture-coordinates, geometry-nodes

So i've been using the attribute sample texture node in blender 2.93. unfortunately it is very unprecise.
in this image the red objects are scattered according to the texture while the white pattern behind represents the actual texture. is there any way to increase the sampling resolution of this node? am i doing something wrong? is this an issue that is being worked on? the sample texture node seems pretty useless if it can't handle any detail
[image: sample]

Answer (score 2):

oops i figured it out. for anyone confused by this, unlike the textures you can use in particle systems, sample texture uses your texture as an attribute, which is similar to vertex colours or weight maps. thus the amount of vertices of your mesh is the resolution. subdivide it to make it more precise.